# Write to end of file

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have managed to write to a text file but I want to be able to add more data to the text file without overwriting the current contents of the text file. So in other words, I want to write to the end of the file each time so it doesn't erase current content. The following code is what I have done so far but it overwrites every time and writes to the beginning, I am not sure how to get it write to the end. Based on this code, the current content in the textfile looks like:

```
June
July
August
September
```

I want to be able to add the following for example

```
 June
 July
 August
 September
 October
```

Does anyone know how to this? Thanks!

```
-(void) writeToTextFile{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/textfile.txt", 
                      documentsDirectory];
//create content - four lines of text
NSString *content = @"June\nJuly\nAugust\nSeptember";
//save content to the documents directory
[content writeToFile:fileName 
          atomically:NO 
            encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy 
               error:nil];

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method to write at End of file:

```
-(void) writeToTextFileWithString:(NSString *) content name:(NSString *) file {

  //TODO: Disable logs at release time

  content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ |||   %@\n",content,[[NSDate date] description]];

  //get the documents directory:
  NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
  NSString *fileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.txt",file]];

  NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:fileName];
  if (fileHandle){

    [fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];
    [fileHandle writeData:[content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [fileHandle closeFile];
  }
  else{

    [content writeToFile:fileName
              atomically:NO
                encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy
                   error:nil];
  }
}
```

Comment: You mean just take the string and add to the end of it?

Comment: I tried this code and it works but it does not save the changes permanently? any other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: check edited answer and what do u mean by it does not save the changes permanently?

Comment: Ahhh I had an extra function in my code that was reading old code. Sorry about that, you are correct and the addition of the new code is also very helpful. Will accept!

Comment: As a note you don't need to check if the file exists and remove it. that is exactly setting atomically does! (sort of) It creates a tmp file and moves it into place once writing is finished. This fixes the potential issue of say the app crashes right before the writeToFile call. You don't have a file (you just removed it) and your string in memory is now toast (the app crashed).

Answer (score 4):

You need to [NSFileHandle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:fileName];
[fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];
[fileHandle writeData:[content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of how to integrate this into my code? thanks

Comment: just simply replace "[content writeToFile:fileName 
          atomically:NO 
            encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy 
               error:nil];" with the codes above

Comment: I will try this immediately and report back. Thank you